# Getting TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'prepareRightAfterWebExtensionInitialize'

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Getting following Error reported for various users for our Office.JS Outlook plugin. It does not happen with all the cases

> TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 
>       'prepareRightAfterWebExtensionInitialize'   at
>       OSF.InitializationHelper.prototype.prepareRightBeforeWebExtensionInitialize(/lib/1/hosted/o15apptofilemappingtable.js:11:153090)
>       at Anonymous function(/lib/1/hosted/Office.js:12:13044)   at
>       d(/lib/1/hosted/Office.js:12:3420)   at
>       f.prototype.waitForFunction(/lib/1/hosted/Office.js:12:3509)   at
>       d(/lib/1/hosted/Office.js:12:12838)
>   at     OSF.DDA.OutlookAppOm.prototype._callAppReadyCallback$p$0(/lib/1/hosted/outlook-15.03.js:17:22743)
>   at Anonymous function(/ajax/3.5/MicrosoftAjax.js:5:298)

Looking at `https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/o15apptofilemappingtable.debug.js`, `prepareRightAfterWebExtensionInitialize` is checked for existence before its use so this error seems odd.

The exact call that fails is:

```js
OfficeJsClient_OutlookWin32.prepareRightAfterWebExtensionInitialize()
```

We are using evergreen version of the `Office.js`. Any pointers how to resolve this or debug it further?

Comment: What is the build and version number of the Outlook client you're seeing this on? Are you calling `prepareRightAfterWebExtensionInitialize` directly? If not, what code are you calling that kicks off this scenario?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT This happens in the initialisation of the Office.js framework. I believe Office.js is calling the function as part of it's internal startup, error occurs before we get the call for the function registered into `Office.initialize`. Above you can see the full stack for the error. We have seen this happen  Windows users, I don't have the exact Outlook client version only a user-agent of the sandboxed browser: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; rv:11.0) like Gecko'

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Also based on the error stack it seems that the users are on Outlook 15.x: `at OSF.DDA.OutlookAppOm.prototype._callAppReadyCallback$p$0(/lib/1/hosted/outlook-15.03.js:17:22743)`

Comment: We cannot repro this issue. Can you share your manifest or a simple way to repro this? Does it work for you in other clients like Desktop Outlook?

Comment: (sorry for previous edits) It looks like we may be able to repro this locally. Updating to the latest version of Outlook 2013 should fix the issue as a workaround.

Comment: (this should only be happening on older versions Outlook 2013)

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Thanks for the feedback and effort +1. As we cannot really control our users platforms is there any workaround we could execute in our end in terms of manifest or the actual plugin code ?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no workaround other than upgrading your Outlook 2013. We are actively working on a solution for this issue and we will communicate with you as soon as it is published.

Comment: Hi @PyryAvist, thank you for your patience. We have fixed the issue and the fix should be available as of build version 15.0.4980.3004.
Let us know if you have any further questions.